# Put first paragraph as filename

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a way to add the first paragraph (user's name) as the Filename.pdf.

I have code to save every new page as a .pdf file.

Now I need every .pdf file to be unique with the user's name written in the first paragraph of the page.

```vb
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20180906
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xPathStr As Variant
    Dim xDictoryStr As String
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xStartPage, xEndPage As Long
    Dim xStartPageStr, xEndPageStr As String
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please chose a valid directory", vbInformation, "Kutools for Word"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xPathStr = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    xStartPageStr = InputBox("Begin saving PDFs starting with page __? " & vbNewLine & "(ex: 1)", "Kutools for Word")
    xEndPageStr = InputBox("Save PDFs until page __?" & vbNewLine & "(ex: 7)", "Kutools for Word")
    If Not (IsNumeric(xStartPageStr) And IsNumeric(xEndPageStr)) Then
        MsgBox "The enterng start page and end page should be number format", vbInformation, "Kutools for Word"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xStartPage = CInt(xStartPageStr)
    xEndPage = CInt(xEndPageStr)
    If xStartPage > xEndPage Then
        MsgBox "The start page number can't be larger than end page", vbInformation, "Kutools for Word"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If xEndPage > ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages) Then
        xEndPage = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)
    End If
    For I = xStartPage To xEndPage
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat xPathStr & "\Page_" & Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select & I & ".pdf", _
        wdExportFormatPDF, False, wdExportOptimizeForPrint, wdExportFromTo, I, I, wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, _
        False, False, wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, True, False, False
    Next
End Sub
```

The section of `Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select` needs to be the first paragraph of every page I am saving to pdf.

Comment: I believe Word MVPs Doug Robbins and Graham Mayor have addressed this in their mail merge utilities. Take a look. https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5AEDCB43615E886B&id=5AEDCB43615E886B!566 http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm I know they handle merging to pdf.

Comment: FYI - In VBA each variable has to be declared as `Dim VariableName as Datatype` so in the declarations `Dim xStartPage, xEndPage As Long` and `Dim xStartPageStr, xEndPageStr As String` only the last variable has a datatype. If the datatype is missed the variable inherits the default datatype of `Variant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you have the username as the first paragraph of each page.

That being the case I would go with something like this:

```
Dim rg As Range, username As String

For i = xStartPage To xEndPage

    Set rg = Activedocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, i)
    Set rg = rg.Paragraphs(1).Range
    rg.Select                                       #<= select for testing only
    username = Replace(rg.Text, vbCr, vbNullString) #<= replacing the paragraph sign at the end with nothing
    
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat xPathStr & "\Page_" & username & i & ".pdf", _
    wdExportFormatPDF, False, wdExportOptimizeForPrint, wdExportFromTo, i, i, wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, _
    False, False, wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, True, False, False
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I couldn't find it on the internet. This works

Answer (score 1):

See *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* or, better still, *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

PS: Although StackOverflow policy is against simply posting links to other sites as answers, I don't propose to re-write code that has been readily available elsewhere for years every time someone tries to reinvent the wheel.